# WADO Protocol implemented in node.js

Tags: node.js, dicom

I am creating a very simple DICOM ECHO server with nodejs however I am facing a problem where the clients always respond as can't connect, I am unsure what I am missing, has someone here experience in writing a DICOM ECHO server?

This is the code I have

```
var net = require('net');
net.createServer(function(socket){
    socket.on('data', function(data){
        datat = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(data));
        console.log(datat);
        socket.write(data);
        socket.end()
    });
    socket.on('error', function(error){
        console.log("Caught server socket error: ")
        console.log(error.stack)
        console.log(error)
    });
}).listen(8041);
console.log('Server running at 127.0.0.1 on port 8041');
```

I have tried responding with the binary data and also with text data but neither one seems to work.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"! And please find a better title for your question!

Comment: @Andreas I did not use tags in the title, the question is about a DICOM implementation in node.js Do you still think it should not be there?

Comment: fair enough ... one could still argue that there is an appended tag *- node.js* ... And, yes, besides that I still think that the title is poorly formulated.

Answer (score 2):

DICOM Echo is not as simple as a ping. You must implement a subset of the full stack of the DICOM network protocol. Instead of writing your own server with node.js, I would advise you to rely on an existing DICOM server. [Orthanc](http://www.orthanc-server.com) is an example of a free DICOM server designed to act as a back-end service to Web applications. Orthanc has built-in support of DICOM C-Echo, which can be triggered by an AJAX request to its [REST API](https://book.orthanc-server.com/users/rest.html) (URI `/modalities/{dicom}/echo`).

*Disclaimer*: I am the author of Orthanc.